# Keyframe animation workflow

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

Been digging through the animation tools in Unreal, trying to find a direct way to set keyframes and edit animation curves on a skeletal mesh. It seems far more complicated than I expected, generally requiring imported poses and animation that is then edited, mixed, etc... in blueprints.

What I am wondering, is there an efficient way to

1. take a skeleton,
2. position and keyframe its bones *in one place not with multiple bone transform nodes wired together*
3. then edit the resulting animation curves

so as to set poses and create animation directly in the editor, or is the only reasonable way to keyframe and edit curves when using Unreal is in an external program?

If it is practical, what editor panes, blueprint nodes, and game objects would I use?

Comment: ( I come from a Maya background, so using a DCC is not a problem, just looking for the most efficient approach. I do not think this is an opinion based question: using an axe to split wood is clearly more practical than using a butter knife. It may not be so cut and dry with Unreal, but if it is I would like to know before wasting too much time going down the wrong path. )

Comment: Unfortunately UE4 has very little tools for animation editing. there are some marketplace plugin that allows you to do so, but i don't own them so I don't know how good they are. The basic tools that comes with UE4 for animation editing are basically useless as many other parts of the engine.